# useBean class attribute value for list of custom class

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have just started learning JSP & servlet. As per my knowledge, we can set a session attribute from servlet and use it in the jsp using jsp:useBean.

Now I have a custom class called Environment, which has certain properties. In the servlet, I am calling a service method which returns List of Environment objects. Then I set the session attribute.

```
List<Environment> environments = eService.fetchEnvironments();
session.setAttribute("environments", environments);
```

And forward request & response objects using RequestDispatcher to the target JSP.
Now I want to access this attribute in JSP. So I do the following in JSP(target JSP):

```
<jsp:useBean id="environments" type="java.util.List<test.project.dto.Environment>"
class="java.util.ArrayList<test.project.dto.Environment>" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
```

fetchEnvironments() method has something like this:

```
List<Environment> environmentList = new ArrayList<Environment>();
//Usual stuff
//Creating & initializing Connection, Statement, Sql string
//etc
ResultSet environments = st.executeQuery(sql);           

while(environments.next())
{
      Environment environment = new Environment();

      environment.setEnvID(environments.getInt(1));
      environment.setEnvName(environments.getString(2));
      environment.setEnvDescription(environments.getString(3));

      environmentList.add(environment);
}
```

When opening above said JSP file I get following error,

```
/EnvironmentManager.jsp (line: 31, column: 2) The value for the useBean class attribute java.util.ArrayList<test.project.dto.Environment> is invalid.
```

So my question is what mistake am I doing in this? Are 'class' and 'type' attributes which I have given correct?

To make the question more constructive: What should be useBean's 'class' & 'type' attribute values when I have a List object of custom class (List< CustomClass >)?

Comment: Why not just expose the list as a request attribute and access/iterate it using JSTL/JSP EL?

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for the reply. Yes! It worked. Apparently session attribute also worked, but only when I pulled it in the jsp using scriptlets <% %>. Any way to do it with useBean only? I know I am missing something very simple here. Probabaly the values of 'class' & 'type' attributes have to be changed but don't know to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs81/pdf/files/workshop/JSPTagsReference.pdf):

Attribute:

```
class="package.class"
Instantiates a bean from a class, using the new keyword and the class 
constructor. The class must not be abstract and must have a public, 
no-argument constructor. The package and class name are case sensitive.
```

```
type="package.class"
If the bean already exists in the scope, gives the bean a data type other than 
the class from which it was instantiated. The value of type must be a 
superclass of class or an interface implemented by class. If you use type 
without class or beanName, no bean is instantiated. The package and class name 
are case sensitive.
```

Try without specifying class as:

```
    <jsp:useBean id="environments" type="java.util.List<test.project.dto.Environment>"
    scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
```

You were using scope as request.

It is always good to start with jstl and el instead of jsp:useBean as pointed by Dave.

Import jstl tag in jsp as:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and iterate over the list as:

```
    <c:forEach items="${environments}" var="environment" varStatus="status1">
           Id: <c:out value="${environment.envId}"/>
           Name: <c:out value="${environment.envName}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prasad. It helped. I had tried that but the silly mistake which I had made was using 'request' in scope, whereas I was setting the attribute in the 'session' scope. Another rookie quesion: Isn't jsp:useBean part of JSTL? Or in other words, can I catch this 'environments' object in JSP without jsp:useBean?

Comment: Yes JSTL EL will look for the attribute specified in page, request, session, and application scopes and will return its value. This is without the support of jsp:useBean. In your scenario, if you are in same session  as setting the list, you can try the above code with jstl and see the output in view. More info can be found on stackoverflow wiki here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 1):

**I solved similar issue as following:**

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>
```

in **java**:

```
request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers()); // List
```

and in **jsp**

```
<jsp:useBean id="users" type="java.util.List<net.roseindia.bean.UserBean>" scope="request"/>
```

and

```
<c:forEach var="currentList" items="${users}">
    <tr>
        <td>${currentList.id}</td>
        <td>${currentList.firstName}</td>
        <td>${currentList.lastName}</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="UserHandler?action=editform&userId=${currentList.id}">Update</a></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="UserHandler?action=delete&userId=${currentList.id}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I hope it will help.

All code here: https://github.com/ashot123/CRUD8